# Slide links not working when exporting as PDF from Keynote

Tags: keynote

I've done a presentation in Keynote. On the first screen I included a few links to different slides. I tested them in Keynote and they're working, however when I export to PDF they're simply not there anymore.

Note that used Export to > PDF and not print as PDF and I also looked in the export settings and saw nothing related to links..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem. I put the link to a slide on items that were grouped together. If I ungrouped the items (I had text inside a circle) and just selected the text and added the link to that, then when I exported to PDF the links worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem running on Keynote 6.6.2 with links to websites not working when exported to PDF. The above answer worked: you have to ungroup assets in Keynote for the links to work in PDF.

**I used keyboard shortcuts to do about 30 in 20 minutes time:**

• Click grouped/linked asset: press <kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>K</kbd> to open Hyperlink option

•   Cut the link from the URL bar with <kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>K</kbd> • Press Enter to leave the
    command

• The group should still be selected; ungroup with
    <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> keyboard shortcut

• The ungrouped assets should be
    individual now; with them still selected do the Hyperlink shortcut
    again: <kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>K</kbd>

• Press the down arrow to select webpage to link to, vs
    the slide number (in my case, or select whichever you were linking
    to) press enter to select.

• Finally, press <kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>V</kbd> to paste in the
    previous linked URL.

• Re-export as PDF from the File>Export option.
    Every link should work now :)

***Ta da! You just flew through the whole thing with the power of keyboard shortcuts!***

Answer (score 0):

Another useful way is to create a shape with 0% opacity and place on top of the objects that you want to link.

I did this because I wanted to have a broader area, not just the text or circle.